# DateTimePicker displays date in wrong format

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a ListView where ID and date is entered. The date is in the format dd/MM/yyyy.

[image]

In the SelectedIndexChanged Property I have written this

```
If lvRecruitmentList.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
   txtID.Text = lvRecruitmentList.SelectedItems(0).Text
   dtpRecievedOn.Text = lvRecruitmentList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
End If
```

In the dtpRecievedOn DateTimePicker, the Date is displayed like this

[image]

I have set the following properties via designer

```
dtpRecievedOn.Format = Custom
dtpRecievedOn.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

**Edit 1** :

Notice that in the ListView the Date is in the format dd/MM/yyyy
and in the  dtpRecievedOn the Date is in the format MM/dd/yyyy.

How can I make dtpRecievedOn display date in the format dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your problem? What is wrong, and what is it that you expected?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Dim str As String() = "2/1/2000".Split("/"C)
Dim dt As New DateTime(Convert.ToInt16(str(2)), Convert.ToInt16(str(1)), Convert.ToInt16(str(0)))
dateTimePicker1.Value = dt.Date
```

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` might be an easier solution.

Comment: According to me No. Reason is - the data is in dd/MM/yyyy format. and by doing parsing will swap the day and month. Please correct me if anything.

Comment: Check [msergeant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868354/datetimepicker-displays-date-in-wrong-format/5870711#5870711)'s answer, there is an example of `ParseExact` (actually, `TryParseExact`, but it works the same way). There is a difference between `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: Please see my comments in his post

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to set the Value of the DateTimePicker as opposed to the Text. You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` to change your text date to a DateTime. Replace your third line with:

```
Dim selectedDate As DateTime
Dim format As String = "dd/MM/yyyy"
Dim txt As String = lvRecruitmentList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
selectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txt, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
dtpRecievedOn.Value = selectedDate
```

Comment: if you use this code with the below mentioned date as the data is in dd/MM/yyyy format according to the author. It will not work.                                                          string dateString, format;
            dateString = "06/15/2008";
            format = "d";

            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            DateTime result;
            
            if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None,out result))
            {
                string str = "";
            }

Comment: Correct, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` should be used instead of `null` or `CurrentCulture`.

Comment: In the tryexactparse function it is set to null . A variable is declared for culture but not used.